# Python function to format output record and write to file is not working

Tags: python, function

A client requires output in a specific format.  I have a pipe delimited file with 4 fields as input; note id, note date, note user, note text.  The input note text can be anywhere from 10 characters to 150 characters.  The logic to format the output record requires inserting a caret (^) at a word break at or before 72 characters up to a maximum overall field length of 1981 characters.  The logic also requires separate output records by date.  Rather than repeat the rather involved coding I want to use a function to format and write the output record, but it keeps failing and I am stumped.

The error message is:

```
Unhandled exception while debugging...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\test_scripts\Outbound_Notes.py", line 137, in <module>
    Output_Note(hold_note)
  File "C:\Python37\test_scripts\Outbound_Notes.py", line 49, in Output_Note
    y = len(hold_word[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my script

```
import string
import sys
import os

# hard codedd file-names for testing.
ifilename = 'TEST_INPUT.DAT'
ofilename = 'TEST_OUTPUT.TXT'

#ifilename = sys.argv[1].replace("\\", "/")
#ofilename = sys.argv[2].replace("\\", "/")

acctNbrOutput = False
hold_id = ''

def Output_Note(note_text):
    maxnote1 = 72
    maxnote2 = 1981
    i = 0
    w = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0
    hold_word = note_text.split()
    word_count = len(note_text.split())
    temp_note = hold_user
    z = 6
    w = 6
    while i <= word_count:
        y = len(hold_word[i])
        w = w + y
        if w < maxnote2:
            w = w + 1
            z = z + 1
            if (z + y) < maxnote1:
                temp_note = temp_note + " " + hold_word[i]                            
                z = z + y
            elif (z + y) >= maxnote1:
                temp_note = temp_note + "^" + hold_word[i] 
                z = y
#           end if
        else:
            noteRecord = '12001' + hold_date + '   ' + temp_note + '\n'
            outputRecord = noteRecord
            f2.write(outputRecord)
            temp_note = hold_user
            z = 6
            w = 6
            temp_note = temp_note + " " + hold_word[i]                            
            z = z + y
            w = w + y
#       end if
        i = i + 1
#   end while loop
    if temp_note != hold_user:
        noteRecord = '12001' + hold_date + '   ' + temp_note + '\n'
        outputRecord = noteRecord
        f2.write(outputRecord)
#   end if

with open(ifilename, 'r') as f1:
    f1.seek(0) #ensure you're at the start of the file..
    first_char = f1.read(1) #get the first character
    if not first_char:
        print("file is empty") #first character is the empty string.
        open(ofilename, "w+").close()
    else:
        f1.seek(0) #first character wasn't empty, return to start of file.
        with open(ofilename, 'w') as f2:  
#           maxnote1 = 72
#           maxnote2 = 1981
#           loop through each record in the notes input file
            for line in f1:
                line = line.strip()
                split_note = line.split('|')
                note_id = split_note[0]
                note_date = split_note[1]
                note_user = split_note[2]
                note_text = split_note[3]
# When the first note is read, initialize the hold fields.                          
                if not hold_id:
                    print(hold_id)
                    hold_id = note_id
                    hold_date = note_date
                    hold_user = note_user
                    hold_note = note_text
                    acctRecord = '10001' + str(hold_id).zfill(10) + '\n'
                    outputRecord = acctRecord
                    f2.write(outputRecord)
                    acctNbrOutput = True
# If the notes have all been read for the patient
                elif hold_id != note_id:
                    if not acctNbrOutput:
                        acctRecord = '10001' + str(hold_id).zfill(10) + '\n'
                        outputRecord = acctRecord
                        f2.write(outputRecord)
                        acctNbrOutput = True
#                   end if
                    Output_Note(hold_note)
                    outputRecord = '19999' + '\n'
                    f2.write(outputRecord)
                    hold_id = note_id
                    hold_date = note_date
                    hold_user = note_user
                    hold_note = note_text
                    acctRecord = '10001' + str(hold_id).zfill(10) + '\n'
                    outputRecord = acctRecord
                    f2.write(outputRecord)
                    acctNbrOutput = True
# If file contains notes from multiple dates                    
                elif hold_date != note_date:
                    if not acctNbrOutput:
                        acctRecord = '10001' + str(hold_id).zfill(10) + '\n'
                        outputRecord = acctRecord
                        f2.write(outputRecord)
                        acctNbrOutput = True
#                   end if
                    Output_Note(hold_note)
                    hold_date = note_date
                    hold_note = note_text
                else:
                    hold_note = hold_note + ' ' + note_text
#               end if
#           end for loop
            if not acctNbrOutput:
                acctRecord = '10001' + str(hold_id).zfill(10) + '\n'
                outputRecord = acctRecord
                f2.write(outputRecord)
                acctNbrOutput = True
#           end if
            Output_Note(hold_note)
            outputRecord = '19999' + '\n'
            f2.write(outputRecord)
            outputRecord = '**END'
            f2.write(outputRecord)
#   end if
#end if
```

Comment: Try to reduce it to a minimal example. Don't just dump your whole script here. Most of the time, you will see the error yourself doing so

Comment: Useful reading: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Replace `while i <= word_count:` by `while i < word_count:`. In your code `i` can be equal to `word_count`, but `hold_word` only has values for indices 0 till `word_count - 1`. 

I agree with FlyingTeller that you should try to make a smaller application that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Always try to minimize your code to only feature your error. In your case, the error appears in the line

```
  y = len(hold_word[i])
```

Collecting the stuff neccessary to have everything defined here, gives you this:

```
note_text = "Some example line\n" #I have no idea what your input might look like
hold_word = note_text.split()
word_count = len(note_text.split())
while i <= word_count:
    y = len(hold_word[i])
    i=i+1
```

This is all the code neccessary to reproduce your error! Now its time to check the error message: `**IndexError: list index out of range**`, so it seems like the index `i` to access the list gets too large. With the minimal example, we can quickly tell what the largest possible value of `i` is, since `i<=word_count` and `word_count = len(note_text.split())`, the largest value of `i` is `len(note_text.split())`, but the largest index in the list is `len(note_text.split()) - 1`, so change your condition in the while to make sure that the index is smaller than the lebgth always:

```
note_text = "Some example line\n"
hold_word = note_text.split()
word_count = len(note_text.split())
while i < word_count: #Note, now < instead of <=
    y = len(hold_word[i])
    i=i+1
```

**Notes**:

1) Don't repeat yourself, you are doing `note_text.split()` twice, better write:

```
hold_word = note_text.split()
word_count = len(hold_word)
```

2) As far as I can see, you are only using `i` to access the list at an index, so you could change your `while` loop into a for loop:

```
for word in hold_word
```

and then use `word` instead of `hold_word[i]`